# Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, telerik, etl

The following is error I am getting. Please help on this.

```
Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException was unhandled by user code
  Message=No metadata has been registered for class Ind.Data.IndiStage.Academy. (This usually indicates, that either this class is not declared persistent or it is declared persistent but not enhanced. The class was loaded from file:///C:/Users/suresh/Documents/WorkSpace/Ind_folder/Ind.ETLService/bin/Release/Ind.Data.IndiStage.DLL.)
  Source=Telerik.OpenAccess
  CanRetry=true
  StackTrace:
       at Telerik.OpenAccess.SPI.Backends.ThrowException(Exception e)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.ExceptionWrapper.Throw()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.storagemanager.StorageManagerFactoryBuilder.createSmfForURL()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.storagemanager.StorageManagerFactoryBuilder.createStorageManagerFactory()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PersistenceManagerFactoryImp.createStorageManagerFactory()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PersistenceManagerFactoryBase.init()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PersistenceManagerFactoryImp.init()
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PersistenceManagerFactoryImp..ctor(PropertySet properties, Object classloader)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PersistenceManagerFactoryImp.getPersistenceManagerFactory(PropertySet props)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.BootstrapPMF.getPersistenceManagerFactory(PropertySet props)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.Helper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(PropertySet props)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DatabaseAdapter.AssertPersistenceManagerFactory(String usr, String password, Boolean open)
       at OpenAccessRuntime.DatabaseAdapter.GetObjectScope(TransactionProvider provider)
       at Telerik.OpenAccess.Database.GetObjectScope(TransactionProvider provider)
       at Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessContextBase.GetScope()
       at Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessContext.GetAllCore[T]()
       at Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessContext.GetAll[T]()
       at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: More information needed. Have you tried adding "metadata" to the Academy class? Is it not declared persistent or is persistent but not enhanced? Start by exploring the error message for a sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

wow.
I got a hardtime to get rid of this exception. "No metadata has been registered for class" with Telerik OpenAccess.

read this article **especially you use CI build system like TeamCity**: http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/integrating-data-access-in-your-solution/external-tools-howto-integrate-enhancer-msbuild